# What does Python's io.open() use as the default separator?

Tags: python, io

So I have a code that's trying to get all lines of a text file inside `message`, by doing this:

```
inbody = False
lines = []
f = io.open(path, 'r', encoding='latin1')
for line in f:
    if inbody:
        lines.appned(line)
    elif line == '\n':
        inbody = True
f.close()
message = '\n'.join(lines)
```

The aim is to get all the lines of a text file inside `message`.

The line `for line in f` indicates that `f` is iterable, which leads me to believe that `io.open()` returns an iterable sequence. My question is: what separator does `io.open()` use to generate this sequence out of a text file?

Answer (score 1):

From https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readline:

> The line terminator is always b'\n' for binary files; for text files,
>   the newline argument to open() can be used to select the line
>   terminator(s) recognized.

Answer (score 0):

From https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open:

> On input, if newline is None, universal newlines mode is enabled. Lines in the input can end in '\n', '\r', or '\r\n', and these are translated into '\n' before being returned to the caller. If it is '', universal newlines mode is enabled, but line endings are returned to the caller untranslated. If it has any of the other legal values, input lines are only terminated by the given string, and the line ending is returned to the caller untranslated.